# Using JWT Token in Client API

Tags: api, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, jwt

I have an API in .NET5 uses JWTBearer to secure the API. Now I wanted to configure my client app to use the token generated from the api/gettoken. It works fine in swagger, but I don't know how to configure my MVC and API(consuming API) to use this token. Can somebody help by providing the configureservices and configure methods in the startup

To Glenn,

I have 3 projects JWT.IDP, JWT.API, JWT.MVC. JWT.IDP issues the token, my intention is to use that token in JWT.API and call the JWT.API function from JWT.MVC. The IDP is working perfectly, I can generate the token and my JWT.MVC Login controller is able to receive it. The last function in the below code (GetWeatherData) is coded according to the idea you have given. If I don't pass the token, I used to get 401 error, now I get 500 Internal Server Error

```
namespace JWT.MVC.Controllers
{
    public class LoginController : Controller
    {

        public IActionResult DoLogin()
        {

            return View();
        }


        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DoLogin([Bind("EmailOrName,Password")] LoginRequestModel loginRequestModel)
        {
            var apiName = $"https://localhost:44318/api/User/login";

            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(apiName, loginRequestModel);
            var jasonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

            var data = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<IEnumerable<AccessibleDb>>
                    (jasonString, new JsonSerializerOptions() { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true });

            foreach (var item in data)
            {
                item.UserName = loginRequestModel.EmailOrName;
            }

            return View("SelectDatabase" , data);
        }

      
        public async Task<IActionResult> PostLogin(string db, string user)
        {
            TokenRequestModel tokenRequestModel = new TokenRequestModel() { Database = db, UserName = user };

            var apiName = $"https://localhost:44318/api/User/tokenonly";

            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(apiName, tokenRequestModel);
            var jasonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

            var data = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<AuthenticationModel>
                    (jasonString, new JsonSerializerOptions() { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true });

            var stream = data.Token;
            var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var jsonToken = handler.ReadToken(stream);
            var tokenS = jsonToken as JwtSecurityToken;
            var selectedDb = tokenS.Claims.First(claim => claim.Type == "Database").Value;

            ViewBag.SelectedDb = selectedDb;

            return View(data);
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> GetWeatherData(string token)
        {

            var apiName = $"https://localhost:44338/weatherforecast";

            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(apiName);
            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                ViewBag.Error = response.StatusCode;
                return View("Weatherdata");
            }
            var jasonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
            var data = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<WeatherForecast>
                    (jasonString, new JsonSerializerOptions() { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true });

        
            return View("Weatherdata" , data);
        }
    }
}
```

Startup class for JWT.MVC is as below

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
             .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
             {

                 options.Audience = "SecureApiUser";
                 options.Authority = "https://localhost:44318";
                 options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                 {
                     ValidateAudience = false
                 };
             });

          
        }
```

Startup class for JWT.API is as below

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddControllers();
            //Copy from IS4
            services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
              .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
              {
                  
                  options.Audience = "SecureApiUser";
                  options.Authority = "https://localhost:44318";
                  options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                  {
                      ValidateAudience = false
                  };
              });

          
            //End
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "JWT.API", Version = "v1" });
            });
        }
```

Startup class for JWT.IDP is as below

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddControllers();

            //Configuration from AppSettings
            services.Configure<JwtSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("JWT"));
            //User Manager Service
            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityDbContext>();
            services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();
            //Adding DB Context with MSSQL
            services.AddDbContext<IdentityDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("IdentityDbConnectionString"),
                    b => b.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(IdentityDbContext).Assembly.FullName)));

            //Adding Athentication - JWT
            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
                .AddJwtBearer(o =>
                {
                    o.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                    o.SaveToken = false;
                    o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                        ValidateIssuer = true,
                        ValidateAudience = true,
                        ValidateLifetime = true,
                        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(Convert.ToInt32(Configuration["JWT:DurationInMinutes"])),
                        ValidIssuer = Configuration["JWT:Issuer"],
                        ValidAudience = Configuration["JWT:Audience"],
                        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["JWT:Key"]))
                    };
                });

           

            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "JWT.IDP", Version = "v1" });
            });
        }
```

And the JWT Setting is as below

```
 "JWT": {
    "key": "C1CF4B7DC4C4175B6618DE4F55CA4",
    "Issuer": "http://localhost:44318",
    "Audience": "SecureApiUser",
    "DurationInMinutes": 60
  },
```

Comment: Hi Jacob, try the Microsoft Docs. It's really an immensely helpful resource and you should be able to find your answer there. For example, start by reading [Authenticate with bearer tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/secure-net-microservices-web-applications/#authenticate-with-bearer-tokens). Then if you have specific questions about implementation, come back and we'll try to help you!

Comment: Thank you Dennis. I will try and let you know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is

```
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
  new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", [token])
```

Keep "Bearer" as it is, it's just a constant. Replace [token], with the base 64 encoded token value returned to us from the OAuth protocol you are using.

Comment: Hello GlennSills, Thank you for such a simple solution. I am still trying to get this thing right. I completed the API issuing the token, but if I have multiple clients to use that token. I have the following questions can you please help.
1. Do we have to give anything in the startup or only your above suggestion is sufficient. 2. The aud settings for JWT, how can we pass multiple audiences 
3. How will my client API or MVC identify itself as one of the audience

Comment: 1) No, putting this in the startup will not work. Think about it, tokens are short lived - you get one and then you authenticate. If you have a lot requests using the same token and you want to avoid coding it in every location then I'd suggest writing a wrapper class that initializizes the HttpClient object. Then have all those places that need to use an HttpClient with at token call that.

Comment: 2) When you request a token you can request 1 o rmore audiences.  When the server create a token it can be for 1 or more audiences.

Comment: 3) When you provision a client on the server, you define the set of audiences it is allowed to request when it asks for a token.

Comment: Hello Glenn, Thank you very much for the explanation. Please consider me as a starter. I am really happy to have contact with you. I understand the first point, I will figure out how to do that. but regarding point 2 and 3 I need your help. If I post my code will you be able to help?

Comment: Hello Glen, I added another controller to my IDP project and tried implementing your solution and it worked. SO now if you can let me know how to pass this token to another API I will be much obliged. Or should I post another request for this?

Comment: Hello Glenn, Can you help me?

Comment: Hi Jacob. Trying to sort this out via comments is not going to work out - there is entirely too much that you would need to know. What I usually suggest to a junior developer who starts with me is to work through the getting started tutorials here:  https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstarts/0_overview.html.  Once you get through these you will generally have all the knowledge you required.

Comment: PS: It will take you about 3 days, but all my co-workers agree that it was well worth it.

Comment: Thank you, Glenn. I managed to implement it with IdentityServer4. Looks like it's paid now. I was trying to do without IS4. There everything looks like is controlled by APIScopes, is there anything like that we can create in JWT, or its only with IS4

Comment: Yeah scopes confused me too. Think of a scope as a particular API (or part of your app). You might want to let some clients access some APIs (scopes) but not others. For example, you might have a scope for the readonly API methods and another one read/write API methods.  You define all these on the OAuth server (like IdentityServer) and then whe you define clients you specify which scopes each client is allowed to access.

Comment: When make the call from the client to get the token, you specify which SCOPES you are interested it. If the OAuth server sees that the client was configured to access all the SCOPES, the login succeeds. Make sense?

Comment: 100% it makes sense. As you guessed, I am not an advanced user like you. You helped me a lot, if I am not asking too much, I uploaded my project in Github https://github.com/jpthomas74/JWTTokenProject. Can you please have a look and suggest the correction. Please? If I had an option to pay for your services, I would be happy to do so. This is so important for me.

Comment: Hi Glenn, I solved it. Thank you for all your efforts and time spent.

Comment: Good for you Jacob! Thanks are payment enough.