# Use JWT token in multiple projects

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, jwt

I have 3 projects JWT.IDP, JWT.API, JWT.MVC.

1. JWT.IDP - an API project validates user and issues the JWT token.
2. JWT.API - an API project for my business logic, CURD etc
3. JWT.MVC - an MVC application for UI.

My intention is to use this token generated in JWT.IDP and call the JWT.API functions from JWT.MVC

The IDP token is working perfectly fine, I can generate the token and my JWT.MVC Login controller is able to receive it. But when I am trying to use this token to access the JWT.API it gives a 500 error (Please see the last function in the below code (GetWeatherData)).

Can someone help, I am not an advanced user, the code written below is taken from several samples. So I am not sure whether it really is the right code.

```
namespace JWT.MVC.Controllers
{
    public class LoginController : Controller
    {

        public IActionResult DoLogin()
        {

            return View();
        }


        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DoLogin([Bind("EmailOrName,Password")] LoginRequestModel loginRequestModel)
        {
            var apiName = $"https://localhost:44318/api/User/login";

            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(apiName, loginRequestModel);
            var jasonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

            var data = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<IEnumerable<AccessibleDb>>
                    (jasonString, new JsonSerializerOptions() { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true });

            foreach (var item in data)
            {
                item.UserName = loginRequestModel.EmailOrName;
            }

            return View("SelectDatabase" , data);
        }

      
        public async Task<IActionResult> PostLogin(string db, string user)
        {
            TokenRequestModel tokenRequestModel = new TokenRequestModel() { Database = db, UserName = user };

            var apiName = $"https://localhost:44318/api/User/tokenonly";

            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(apiName, tokenRequestModel);
            var jasonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

            var data = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<AuthenticationModel>
                    (jasonString, new JsonSerializerOptions() { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true });

            var stream = data.Token;
            var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var jsonToken = handler.ReadToken(stream);
            var tokenS = jsonToken as JwtSecurityToken;
            var selectedDb = tokenS.Claims.First(claim => claim.Type == "Database").Value;

            ViewBag.SelectedDb = selectedDb;

            return View(data);
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> GetWeatherData(string token)
        {

            var apiName = $"https://localhost:44338/weatherforecast";

            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(apiName);
            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                ViewBag.Error = response.StatusCode;
                return View("Weatherdata");
            }
            var jasonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
            var data = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<WeatherForecast>
                    (jasonString, new JsonSerializerOptions() { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true });

        
            return View("Weatherdata" , data);
        }
    }
}
```

Startup class for JWT.MVC is as below

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
             .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
             {

                 options.Audience = "SecureApiUser";
                 options.Authority = "https://localhost:44318";
                 options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                 {
                     ValidateAudience = false
                 };
             });

          
        }
```

Startup class for JWT.API is as below

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddControllers();
            //Copy from IS4
            services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
              .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
              {
                  
                  options.Audience = "SecureApiUser";
                  options.Authority = "https://localhost:44318";
                  options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                  {
                      ValidateAudience = false
                  };
              });

          
            //End
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "JWT.API", Version = "v1" });
            });
        }
```

Startup class for JWT.IDP is as below

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddControllers();

            //Configuration from AppSettings
            services.Configure<JwtSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("JWT"));
            //User Manager Service
            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityDbContext>();
            services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();
            //Adding DB Context with MSSQL
            services.AddDbContext<IdentityDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("IdentityDbConnectionString"),
                    b => b.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(IdentityDbContext).Assembly.FullName)));

            //Adding Athentication - JWT
            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
                .AddJwtBearer(o =>
                {
                    o.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                    o.SaveToken = false;
                    o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                        ValidateIssuer = true,
                        ValidateAudience = true,
                        ValidateLifetime = true,
                        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(Convert.ToInt32(Configuration["JWT:DurationInMinutes"])),
                        ValidIssuer = Configuration["JWT:Issuer"],
                        ValidAudience = Configuration["JWT:Audience"],
                        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["JWT:Key"]))
                    };
                });

           

            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "JWT.IDP", Version = "v1" });
            });
        }
```

And the JWT Setting is as below

```
 "JWT": {
    "key": "C1CF4B7DC4C4175B6618DE4F55CA4",
    "Issuer": "http://localhost:44318",
    "Audience": "SecureApiUser",
    "DurationInMinutes": 60
  },
```

Comment: This looks like the same question you have here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67662711/using-jwt-token-in-client-api. In any case, if you get a 500 error, as a minimum you need to post the error message/output from the server that is producing it.

Comment: No Shaun, the question there was different. There I wanted to know how to pass JWT to an API for which I got the answer, after marking that as the answer only my next challenge came in. Since the person who helped me there seems very knowledgeable I thought of posting the problem there, but he's not responding that's why it's created as a new post here. By the way, Do you know the solution, can you help?

Comment: As I said, you really need to say what the actual error is that is causing the 500 error code. Look at the output from the server or try to extract more information from the response. Just a 500 code isn't enough.

Comment: Shaun, I tried for the last 12 hours to see the reason for the internal error. I am not able to get anything more than an internal error. The error is in the LoginController, GetWheatherData on code  HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(apiName); Here the response object's IsSuccessStatusCode is false and if you evaluate the response object in debug mode it shows InternalServerError. Can you please help

Comment: You need to debug the server code -  i.e. the API implementation in `GetWeatherData`. The LoginController is the client in this case.

Comment: Kind of like you I'm trying to create a Single SIgn On jwt token authentication api in .net core, that will be used for other apps and projects as authentication mechanism. Can you give me a tutorial where is explained how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite surprising that no one was able to identify the mistake. I made the following changes and it works perfectly fine now.

The ConfigureServices is like below in both MVC and API projects. No other changes to any other codes.

```
         public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddControllers();

            var authenticationProviderKey = "IdentityApiKey";
            var signingKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("C1CF4B7DC4C4175B6618DE4F55CA4"));
            var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = signingKey,
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidIssuer = "http://localhost:44318",
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidAudience = "SecureApiUser",
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
                RequireExpirationTime = true,
            };

            services.AddAuthentication(o =>
            {
                o.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = authenticationProviderKey;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(authenticationProviderKey, x =>
            {
                x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                x.TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters;
            });

            //services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            //{
            //    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            //    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

            //}).AddJwtBearer(options =>
            //{
            //    options.Authority = "https://localhost:44318"; ;
            //    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            //    options.Audience = "SecureApiUser";
            //});

            //End

            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "JWT.API2", Version = "v1" });
            });
        }
```